# How to append an element which is generated embedded by an XSLT multiple times

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT 1.0:

I have this following xml as input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
  <Sub1>
      <Val1>A</Val1>
      <Val3>C</Val3>
  </Sub1>
  <Sub2>
      <Val2>NIL</Val2>
    <Val4>D</Val4>
  </Sub2>
</Root>
```

and my XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


  <xsl:template match="/Root">

    <xsl:element name ="New">

      <xsl:apply-templates select="Sub1"/>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="Sub2"/>

    </xsl:element>


  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sub1" >
    <xsl:variable name='pr' select='.'/>

    <xsl:element name="Myelement1"  >
      <!-- The value should be added to the output regardless-->
      <xsl:value-of select="$pr/Val1"/>

      <xsl:if test="number($pr/Val1) = $pr/Val1">

        <!--TWO things should be done:
    1- Check if     <messages> is created in the output XML? if not it should be created
    2- A message Should be added to     <Messages> like     <Message> Myelement1 is not numeric    </Message>--> 

      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="Sub2" >
      <xsl:variable name='pr' select='.'/>

      <xsl:element name="Myelement2"  >
        <!-- The value should be added to the output regardless-->
        <xsl:value-of select="$pr/Val2"/>

        <xsl:if test="$pr/Val2='NIL'">

          <!--TWO things should be done:
      1- Check if     <messages> is created in the output XML? if not it should be created
      2- A message Should be added to     <Messages> like     <Message> Myelement2 is not valid    </Message>-->

        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The current XSLT generates the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<New>
  <Myelement1>A</Myelement1>
  <Myelement2>NIL</Myelement2>
</New>
```

but here is what I actually want:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <New>
    <Myelement1>A</Myelement1>
    <Myelement2>NIL</Myelement2>

   <Messages>
     <Message> Myelement1 is not numeric </Message>
     <Message> Myelement2 is not valid </Message>
   </Messages>
 </New>
```

My problem is the Messages element.

This element is dynamic and the number of message sub-elements could vary and are dependent on the source XML’s content.

It could also be empty but the big problem is that I want to add those message sub-elements at runtime while the XSLT is  navigating through  the source xml file using multiple templates , etc.

So let’s say,  I have got two DIFFERENT templates to generate Myelement1 and  Myelement2 named Temp1 and temp2 so I want to add a few messages ( not constant messages and could be anything) under messages element while the applied template (temp1) is being executed and then a few more DIFFERENT messages ( not constant messages) when the second template ( temp2) is being executed .

for example
if A is not numeric it should be a message like below should be added under messages

```
<message> myelement1 is not in a correct format < Message>
```

Think about the messages element as a log or error element.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry but this is very unclear.  You need to explain in much greater detail, _with example XML and XSL_, how the `<Message>` elements are generated.

Comment: @JimGarrison Just added an example

Comment: That's fine, but HOW is it generated? Where is the decision made to add a message?

Comment: @JimGarrison , I have updated the question again. hopefully this time, it's clear

Comment: If I understand your question correctly (?), you need to do this in two steps: first, have your templates write to a variable. Then process the variable (after converting it to a node-set) and combine the two groups of messages into one. Either that or change your  overall approach. I don't know of a way to have a template write to two different locations in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in two passes. In the first pass, you could store the results in a variable, where the `Message` elements are simply created after any new element you create or change.

Then in the second pass, you can simply change the location of any `Message` element that exists, although in XSLT 1.0 you will have to make use of the `node-set` extension function to do this, as the variable you create to hold the first pass will be a "Result Tree Fragment". The exslt node-set function is widely supported, so you should be able to use that.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="pass1">
      <xsl:element name ="New">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Sub1"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Sub2"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($pass1)" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" mode="pass2" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sub1" >
    <xsl:variable name='pr' select='.'/>
    <xsl:element name="Myelement1"  >
       <xsl:value-of select="$pr/Val1"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="not(number($pr/Val1) = $pr/Val1)">
      <Message>Myelement1 is not numeric</Message>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Sub2" >
    <xsl:variable name='pr' select='.'/>
    <xsl:element name="Myelement2"  >
      <xsl:value-of select="$pr/Val2"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="$pr/Val2='NIL'">
      <Message>Myelement2 is not valid</Message>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="pass2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />    
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="New[Message]" mode="pass2">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::Message)]" mode="pass2" />
      <Messages>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Message" mode="pass2" />
      </Messages>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh3t

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use separate templates for each section of your output. Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <elemA>alpha</elemA>
    <elemB>55</elemB>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="elemA | elemB"/>
        <Messages>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="elemA | elemB" mode="messages"/>        
        </Messages>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elemA">
    <Myelement1>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </Myelement1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elemB">
    <Myelement2>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </Myelement2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elemA" mode="messages">
    <xsl:if test="not(number(.)=number(.))">
        <Message>Myelement1 is not a number.</Message>
     </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="elemB" mode="messages">
    <xsl:if test=". > 50">
        <Message>Myelement2 is greater than 50.</Message>
     </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <Myelement1>alpha</Myelement1>
  <Myelement2>55</Myelement2>
  <Messages>
    <Message>Myelement1 is not a number.</Message>
    <Message>Myelement2 is greater than 50.</Message>
  </Messages>
</output>
```